# Image of a function with multiple variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

I'm studying multiple variable functions, and a doubt appeared:
When I have the function
$f(x,y) = (x, y, x^2 + y^2)$, how can I see the image of the function? Because, the first two coordinates are valid in all the $\mathbb{R}^3$, but the third only in $\mathbb{R}^3 > 0$, so, how can I know the image of the function $f$?

Comment: The image of $f$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ above the $xy$-plane.  (Or on and above the $xy$-plane to be exact.)  In fact, it's the graph of the cone $z=x^2+y^2.$

Comment: If I write that the image is the set ${(x, y, z) | x, y \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{R} > 0}$, is it correct?

Comment: its not a cone , its a paraboloid. Equation of a cone is $z^2 = x^2+y^2$ and equation of a paraboloid is $z = x^2+y^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other people have said in their comments (@saulspatz, @drhab), the image of $f$ is the graph of the cone given by $z=x^2 + y^2$. But there is more to that...

In general, we mathematicians (and at some point you might be one) do what we can to represents objects graphically. Our vision is severely constrained by the three dimensions we can observe, and all too often we have to resort to sketchy drawings on the board or on paper. Of course one can (and it is often a good idea) ask a computer program to plot a function for us.

In this case, do note that the first two entries of $(x,y,x^2 + y^2$ are precisely the two arguments of the function $f$. So it should be enough to 'draw' $x,y,x^2 + y^2$ in order to see the 'image of the function'. This time round, we know that this corresponds to the cone above, so you would be done with the drawing part.

Replying to your comment asking if the image was the set $\{(x,y,z)|x,y,\in\mathbb{R}, z>0\}$, the answer is no. Mind that not every positive $z$ will be in the image for every positive pair $(x,y)$. For each pair $(x,y)$, only the $z\in\mathbb{R}$ **such that** $z = x^2 + y^2$ will be there. So, in notation, this means that the image is precisely the set
$$\{(x,y,x^2 + y^2)|x,y,\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

If you want to see it visually, cut a slice parallel to the $XY$ plane at any height $h\geq 0$. This slice will intersect the cone at the points that are at a distance $\sqrt{h}$ from the $OZ$ axis. The image will be formed by the collection of all the points in the intersections of the many slices with the cone.

Please reply if you have further questions, I will be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks you so much,Sam, helped me a lot. I don't know if this is the properly place, but, can you recommend me contents about functions in R^n and continuity and differenciability in R^n?

Comment: My pleasure! In order to point you in a convenient direction, I think it'd be wiser for me to ask what you already know, in terms of: what have you read so far? What can you do?

Comment: The subject i'm studying is Calculus III - Series and Differenciable Functions, and now I am starting the study of differenciable functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I've alredy studied functions with two and three variables in Calculus II and with one variable in Calculus I.

Comment: Have you read Spivak's Calculus? It's quite enlightening for single-variable functions. For several variables, we have the likes of Marsden-Tromba (quite visual) and Marsden-Hoffman (quite rigorous). Once you have a solid command of all of this, maybe Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds could be a nice read. Be aware that it's extremely rigorous; this tiny book takes an awful lot of time to go through, but it's well worth the effort.

Comment: I've heard a lot about Spivak's book, I will try to read it and give a look in Marden's too, thank you so much, Sam!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck ^^

Answer (score 1):

Here, $ f:\Re^2 \rightarrow \Re^3 $ , $~ f(x,y) = (x,y,x^2+y^2) $.

Therefore the image set is $ z= \{x,y\in\Re~|~x^2+y^2 \} $

For visualization purpose, as in $2D~$, function $f(x) = y^2$ is a parabola.

On similar grounds, in $3D~$, function $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2 $ is a paraboloid.

[image]